# Find a bijective function between $\mathbb N$ and $2^{\mathbb N} \times 2^{\mathbb N}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}$$

How can I prove that there is a bijective function between $\N$ and the Cartesian product $2^\N\times 2^\N$?

I've seen a proof and a function for $\N\times\N$ to $\N$. Is it the same?

Comment: By $2^N$, do you mean $2^\mathbb N$, i.e. the power set of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: Utterly impossible. $|\Bbb N|<|2^{\Bbb N}|\le |2^{\Bbb N}\times 2^{\Bbb N}|$.

Comment: There cannot be a bijective function. The power set of $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable.

Comment: @5xum - yes, I mean the power set of N

Comment: @lam3r4370 Good luck finding a function that doesn't exist, then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no bijective function between $\mathbb N$ and $2^\mathbb N$ (the power set of $\mathbb N$), because there is, for any set $X,$ no bijection between $X$ and $2^X$.

For proof, look up [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument).

---

Once you know that, it should be easy to see that, since $|2^\mathbb N|\leq|2^\mathbb N\times 2^\mathbb N|$, there also cannot be a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $2^\mathbb N\times 2^\mathbb N$.

If you want another argument, you can show that a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $2^\mathbb N\times2^\mathbb N$ would allow you to construct an *injective* function from $2^\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$